# Centring progress circle on view for new screen sizes

Tags: ios, swift, drawrect

I have a progress circle in my app that works great for 3.5 and 4 inch screens, however I have just began the process of updating my app for the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus and I have noticed that the progress circle does not function as intended.

The reason for this is that I have hard-coded the progress circle position to be centred on the smaller screens.

I was wondering if anyone could show me what I need to do to convert it so that no matter what screen size, the circles are centred?

Here is my code:

```
class ProgressCircle: UIView {

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    var innerRadiusRatio: CGFloat = 0.6

    var path: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
    var startAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(-M_PI_2)
    var endAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(-M_PI_2) + min(1.0, progress) * CGFloat(M_PI * 2)
    var outerRadius: CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) * 0.5 - 1.0
    var innerRadius: CGFloat = outerRadius * innerRadiusRatio
    var center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect))

    //Code for background circle

    var context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    colourTheme = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("themeSettings")
    if colourTheme == 1 {
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, (UIColorFromRGB(0xEAEAEA)).CGColor)
    } else {
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, (UIColor.darkGrayColor()).CGColor)
    }
    var rectangle: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 171, 171)
    CGContextBeginPath(context)
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle)
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill)

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    if colourTheme == 1 {
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, (UIColor.darkGrayColor()).CGColor)
    } else {
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, (UIColorFromRGB(0xEAEAEA)).CGColor)
    }
    var rectangleSmall: CGRect = CGRectMake(35.95, 35.95, 99.1, 99.1) //102.6
    CGContextBeginPath(context)
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangleSmall)
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill)

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //Code for progress radius

    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, center.x, center.y, innerRadius, startAngle, endAngle, false)
    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, center.x, center.y, outerRadius, endAngle, startAngle, true)
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path)

    CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
    CGContextClip(ctx)
    if percent > 100 {
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, self.bounds, UIImage(named: "RadialProgressFillOver").CGImage)
    } else {
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, self.bounds, UIImage(named: "RadialProgressFill").CGImage)
    }
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
}
```

Comment: Simple with AutoLayout via IB. Are you determined to do so programmatically?

Comment: How are you putting this view on screen?

Comment: @dvdowns Yeah, I've tried using AutoLayout and I really don't like it. There aren't many elements in my app like this so I decided using separate storyboards would be a better solution.

Comment: @user3746428 understood, hope you figure it out

Comment: @rdelmar Ah, thanks for reminding me. The answer was obvious! I just had to adjust the x coordinate calculation for the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It was actually pretty obvious but I had forgotten about the way I was actually adding the progress circle to the view.

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
    var circleFrame = CGRect(x: (budgetDisplayView.bounds.width/2)-85.5, y: 249, width: 171, height: 171)
    var circle = ProgressCircle(frame: circleFrame)
    self.budgetDisplayView.addSubview(circle)
    self.budgetDisplayView.sendSubviewToBack(circle)
```